# Server stops responding after a while

Tags: node.js, express, forever

I am facing a weird problem where I start my **https** server using node **https** module and **self-signed certificate**-

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var https = require("https");    

var privateKey  = fs.readFileSync(require.toUrl(appConfig.get("ssl:key")), 'utf8');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync(require.toUrl(appConfig.get("ssl:cert")), 'utf8');

var credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate};

https.createServer(credentials, app).listen(443);
console.log('listening on port# ' + 443);
```

The server keeps responding to get/put/post requests for few hours and then takes forever to return response to requests.

I am using **forever** module and forever logs give no error or termination commands.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: You should implement your own logs. Catch any and all errors using error event handlers and output them to the console. Additionally you can narrow it down further by logging when certain functions are being called. A hang could simply mean a loop is running wild.

Comment: I actually think you may have just run into a looping problem. Since node runs an "event loop" in a single threaded process, code has the unfortunate ability of blocking IO for synchronous tasks. If you have any synchronous tasks that never complete, your application will basically just hang/stall. The following code is enough to cause any vanilla node application to hang forever and not do anything: `for(i=0;i>-1;i++) void(0);`

Comment: I ll cross check this if there is an infinite loop.The same code has been running on port 80 since 1.5 years. I dnt know the problem exists only with https server.

Comment: i implemented memory monitoring and there were no leaks or infinite loops found. the problem was solved once i changed Connection header to "close" rather than keep-alive

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out,we had a ping api which was coming from the clients and  **'Connection'** header was set to default value  **keep-alive** which was keeping the connections open .

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Seems like this might work. From where should this header value be applied? Is it a configuration of the server side, or from the client which sends the ping request?

Answer (score 0):

Since there are no logs, its going to be hard to tell, but try this:

```
    var app = require("express")();
    var privateKey  = fs.readFileSync(require.toUrl(appConfig.get("ssl:key")), 'utf8');
    var certificate = fs.readFileSync(require.toUrl(appConfig.get("ssl:cert")), 'utf8');
    var credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate};
    var https = require("https").Server(credentials, app);
    https.listen(443, function() {
    console.log('listening on port# ' + 443);
    });
```

secondly, are u sure no other service is interfering on port 443?